# How do I send a text String to C and return a similar back to Swift

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode

I have an optimised C program that executes perfectly, taking a text string inputted via keyboard, processes it and spits out a series of strings of same size/length (to console at present.
I want to substitute the keyboard entered input with a String sent from Swift and then the output sent back to Swift.
I’m confused by the variety of questions/answers on this subject particularly as many of them are outdated and and don’t work with current Swift/Xcode.
I feel I need a mentor (or tranquillisers!)

Comment: Easiest way is put the C code in an Objective-C .m file, write a tiny adapter function that can accept and return NSStrings, that function adapts NSString to C strings. Then using a bridging header your Swift code can see the ObjectiveC code. Hmmm - the ObjectiveC file probably needs to be a class, but that function can be a class method so all in all very simple. Writing this on iPad so hard to edit. The C code can be separately compiled as a .c file, but that ObjC .m file needs to include a .h file with C functions defined.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.